# Encoding problems with sigma-js

Tags: javascript, gephi, sigma.js

If I export Gephi graph to [sigma-js](https://marketplace.gephi.org/plugin/sigmajs-exporter/) and load it locally everything is perfect, but if I upload the contents to a http storage (i.e. dropbox public or other), characters other then ascii display garbage.

I thought that problem is maybe in fancybox (ruled out jquery obviously), but after some modifications it seems that problem is sigma-js. Strangely I didn't find any issue reporting encoding problems on their tracker.

What do you think, makes the code render fine locally and then spit garbage from "server"?

It seems to me that the problem is in their json reader (but who want's to deal with javascript)?

Answer (score 1):

Found solution, and it was easier than I thought. Hopefully it will help others.

Problem indeed was in JSON reader. Having awful experience with UTF-8 and JSON in Python already, my first straw was JSON decoding.
Soon after I tried couple of things before asking the question, I now encoded my JSON data (data.json file exported by sigma-js Gephi plugin) with BOM header and everything is perfect again :)